# Which approach would be best to implement a particle shader with Vulkan API?

Tags: c++, vulkan, particles, particle-system

I am implementing particle shader and it implies drawing lots of rectangles with unique data for each. Now I see different ways to do it.

---

**Way 1:**

1. use a single uniform buffer for all particles
2. do a single vkCmdBindDescriptorSets on drawing start
3. call a single vkCmdDraw with instance count equal to particles count
4. in vertex shader use uniform struct that consist only of single array:

```
struct Particle
{
    //...
};

layout(binding = 0) uniform ParticleUniformBufferObject
{
    Particle particles[MAX_PARTICLES_TO_DRAW];
} ubo;
```

4. Then when drawing use glsl variables to access uniform data

```
vec3 particlePosition = ubo.particles[gl_InstanceID].position;
```

---

**Way 2:**

1. use a single uniform buffer for all particles
2. do vkCmdBindDescriptorSets for each particle using dynamic offset
3. do vkCmdDraw for each particle with instance count 1
4. access to buffer data in vertex shader in a common way without arrays

---

**Way 3:**

Do everything through vertex input and without any per-object uniforms. Probably there would be much of unnecessary data overhead. Vertex buffer should be updated each frame in that case.

---

My question - which way is better in terms of performance?

Or do you see another good approach for particle rendering with Vulkan API?

Comment: http://www.joshbarczak.com/blog/?p=667 this blog post seems to recommend #3 in favor of instancing, but it's not Vulkan and your use case might be different depending on how much vertex data you need to send

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to make use of indirect drawing: [`vkCmdDrawIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdDrawIndirect.html). Such an approach could pay off IF you are able to modify your particles on the GPU only. If you need to animate/modify/etc. them on the CPU, then indirect drawing will not help.

As far as your particle data is concerned, you would store them in a `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT` buffer, modify them in a compute shader pass, and render them with an indirect draw call. To access a particle's data, you would have to use `GLSL`'s built-in `gl_DrawID`.

---

In general, one can not tell which way is better than another way in terms of performance. This depends on so many factors: on how you are going to modify the particles, what they depend on, the number of particles, the used GPU, etc. If you really want to know, you'd have to implement all approaches and measure.

If you are going to do the latter, please share your results and describe your setup! Stuff like that is always interesting.